# Where find more resources on Xperia Touch projector API?

Tags: android, touch, sony

I want to develop app for this: https://www.sonymobile.com/global-en/products/smart-products/xperia-touch/#gref

Has anyone developed an app for this? There is no public API, but Sony claims that it has "full access to Android APIs, it is also possible to access additional Sony APIs that provide extended functionality, such as kiosk mode for public spaces and more".

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We developed an app for Xperia Touch a few months back. It shouldn't give you any trouble, they work really well. It's exactly the same as developing for any other Android device.

Just think carefully of where it will be installed so the sensors work properly and the light conditions are optimal. About the kiosk mode, I believe the Sony API provides some options like that, however, we weren't aware of it at the time and were still able to solve such things with 3rd party apps.